# WMI memory leak issue

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks, windows

I have some `WMI` memory leak issue when changing languages. I have checked it in `Task Manager`. For example, my app takes 25 MB `RAM`, when changing languages it grows to 30 MB and 35, 40... and never release it.

```
//Initialization
IWbemLocator *pLocator = 0;
IWbemServices *pService = 0;
IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
IWbemClassObject *pclsObj = NULL;

while (pEnumerator)
{
      hres = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &pclsObj, &uReturn);

      VARIANT processName;
      pclsObj->Get(L"Name", 0, &processName, 0, 0);
      QString userProcessName;
      userProcessName = QString::fromWCharArray(processName.bstrVal);

      emit testData(userProcessName);
      VariantClear(&processName);
}

//Cleanup
 pService->Release();
 pLocator->Release();
 //pEnumerator->Release(); - Clang Static Analyzer displays issue - called C++ object pointer is null
 //pclsObj->Release(); - Clang Static Analyzer displays issue - called C++ object pointer is null
```

How to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

**Test screenshot where I have checked about memory leak:**

**[image]**

**Code:**

```
int Test::allServicesWMIData()
{
    HRESULT hres;

    // Initialize COM.
    hres = CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        emit initComLibError(QString(QObject::tr("Failed to initialize COM library. Error code =") + " 0x%1").arg(hexErrorData(hres)));
        return 1;              // Program has failed.
    }

    IWbemLocator *pLocator = 0;

    hres = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_WbemLocator,
        0,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *)&pLocator);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        emit errorCreateIWbemObject(QString(QObject::tr("Failed to create IWbemLocator object. Error code =") + " 0x%1").arg(hexErrorData(hres)));
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;       // Program has failed.
    }

    IWbemServices *pService = 0;

    hres = pLocator->ConnectServer(
        _bstr_t(L"ROOT\\CIMV2"), // WMI namespace
        NULL,                    // User name
        NULL,                    // User password
        0,                       // Locale
        NULL,                    // Security flags
        0,                       // Authority
        0,                       // Context object
        &pService                    // IWbemServices proxy
    );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        emit errorRootConnection(QString(QObject::tr("Could not connect. Error code =") + " 0x%1").arg(hexErrorData(hres)));
        pLocator->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;                // Program has failed.
    }

    hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(
        pService,                         // the proxy to set
        RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT,            // authentication service
        RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE,             // authorization service
        NULL,                         // Server principal name
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL,       // authentication level
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,  // impersonation level
        NULL,                         // client identity
        EOAC_NONE                     // proxy capabilities
    );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        emit errorProxyBlanket(QString(QObject::tr("Could not set proxy blanket. Error code =") + " 0x%1").arg(hexErrorData(hres)));
        pService->Release();
        pLocator->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;               // Program has failed.
    }

    IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
    hres = pService->ExecQuery(
        bstr_t("WQL"),
        bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service"),
        WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY,
        NULL,
        &pEnumerator);

    IWbemClassObject *pclsObj = NULL;

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        emit errorProcessQuery(QString(QObject::tr("Query for processes failed. Error code =") + " 0x%1").arg(hexErrorData(hres)));
        pService->Release();
        pLocator->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;               // Program has failed.
    }
    else
    {
        ULONG uReturn = 0;

        while (pEnumerator)
        {
            hres = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &pclsObj, &uReturn);

            VARIANT serviceName;
            VARIANT servicePath;
            VARIANT serviceID;
            VARIANT serviceType;
            VARIANT serviceState;
            VARIANT serviceStatus;
            VARIANT serviceErrorControl;
            VARIANT serviceStartMode;
            VARIANT serviceWaitHint;
            VARIANT serviceExitCode;

            if (hres != 0) {
                emit hardwareDataNotAvailable();
                break;
            } else {
                pclsObj->Get(L"Caption", 0, &serviceName, 0, 0);
                pclsObj->Get(L"PathName", 0, &servicePath, 0, 0);
                pclsObj->Get(L"ProcessId", 0, &serviceID, 0, 0);
                pclsObj->Get(L"ServiceType", 0, &serviceType, 0, 0);
                pclsObj->Get(L"State", 0, &serviceState, 0, 0);
                pclsObj->Get(L"Status", 0, &serviceStatus, 0, 0);
                pclsObj->Get(L"ErrorControl", 0, &serviceErrorControl, 0, 0);
                pclsObj->Get(L"StartMode", 0, &serviceStartMode, 0, 0);
                pclsObj->Get(L"WaitHint", 0, &serviceWaitHint, 0, 0);
                pclsObj->Get(L"ExitCode", 0, &serviceExitCode, 0, 0);
            }

            QString userServiceName = QString::fromWCharArray(serviceName.bstrVal);
            QString userServicePath = QString::fromWCharArray(servicePath.bstrVal);
            QString userServiceID = QString::number(serviceID.uintVal);
            QString userServiceType = QString::fromWCharArray(serviceType.bstrVal);
            QString userServiceState = QString::fromWCharArray(serviceState.bstrVal);
            QString userServiceStatus = QString::fromWCharArray(serviceStatus.bstrVal);
            QString userServiceErrorControl = QString::fromWCharArray(serviceErrorControl.bstrVal);
            QString userServiceStartMode = QString::fromWCharArray(serviceStartMode.bstrVal);
            QString userServiceWaitHint = QString::number(serviceWaitHint.uintVal);
            QString userServiceExitCode = QString::number(serviceExitCode.uintVal);

            emit appAllServicesData(userServiceName, userServicePath, userServiceID, userServiceType, userServiceState, userServiceStatus, userServiceErrorControl,
            userServiceStartMode, userServiceWaitHint, userServiceExitCode);

            VariantClear(&serviceName);
            VariantClear(&servicePath);
            VariantClear(&serviceID);
            VariantClear(&serviceType);
            VariantClear(&serviceState);
            VariantClear(&serviceStatus);
            VariantClear(&serviceErrorControl);
            VariantClear(&serviceStartMode);
            VariantClear(&serviceWaitHint);
            VariantClear(&serviceExitCode);
        }
    }

    // Cleanup
    pService->Release();
    pLocator->Release();
    //pEnumerator->Release(); - Clang Static Analyzer displays issue - called C++ object pointer is null
    //pclsObj->Release(); - Clang Static Analyzer displays issue - called C++ object pointer is null
    CoUninitialize();
    emit finished();
    return 0;   // Program successfully completed.
}
```

Comment: None of the columns in Task Manager show the amount of RAM a process occupies. What value are you really looking at? And why do you assume, that there is a memory leak? Make sure you understand [memory management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366525.aspx).

Comment: If you need to post a screenshot, put it in your question. And use a supported image host. *fastpic.ru* is not a supported image host.

Comment: My app takes memory and never releases it, so should I consider this as not a leak?

Comment: That may or may not be a leak, we don't know. Looking at the code you posted, a memory leak is likely the least of your worries. As posted, the code immediately crashes the process with an access violation. I would advice to post **real** code.

Comment: I can't post all code because it contains about 10 thousand lines, but I will post some code later.

Comment: You aren't asked to post **all** code. On the contrary, you are asked to post a [mcve]. Strong emphasis on *"minimal"*.

Comment: My project is not small, I meant about 10 thousand lines of code just WMI. Here is some example.

Comment: How is that *"minimal"*? Besides, since you tagged this question [tag:c++], why aren't you using smart pointers? That'll save a third of your code that implements manual resource management. I have no idea, why you commented out `pEnumerator->Release();` either. That is a resource leak as documented (see [IWbemServices::ExecQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392107.aspx)). Plus, you don't seem to understand COM well enough to pull this off (none of your `VARIANT`s are initialized, for example).

Comment: I have commented out `//pEnumerator->Release();` because I test it in Clang Static Analyzer and it displays issue - called C++ object pointer is null. From MSDN example I can use uninitialized `VARIANT` [MSDN WMI example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390423(v=vs.85).aspx). Besides, I initialize it later - `pclsObj->Get(L"Caption", 0, &serviceName, 0, 0);`

Now I know where is possible leak and I will try to fix it.

Comment: This question has worth to `upvote`. I `upvoted` either question and answer too. Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@IInspectable

Thank you. I have fixed the `WMI` memory leak issue by releasing resources.

**Code:**

```
...
            VariantClear(&serviceName);
            VariantClear(&servicePath);
            VariantClear(&serviceID);
            VariantClear(&serviceType);
            VariantClear(&serviceState);
            VariantClear(&serviceStatus);
            VariantClear(&serviceErrorControl);
            VariantClear(&serviceStartMode);
            VariantClear(&serviceWaitHint);
            VariantClear(&serviceExitCode);
            pclsObj->Release();
        }
    }

    // Cleanup
    pService->Release();
    pLocator->Release();
    pEnumerator->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
    emit finished();
    return 0;   // Program successfully completed.
}
```